# Can I ignore the key word DEFINED in cmake?

Tags: cmake

I have a simple question related to camke keyword DEFINED. I do not know in which condition this keyword is necessary and in which condition this keyword can be ignored. The following example is given to illustrate my question:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(TEST)

if (NOT ABC)
  set(ABC "hello ABC")
endif()

message(${ABC})

if (ABC)
  message(${ABC})
endif()

if (DEFINED ABC)
  message(${ABC})
endif()
```

As you can see from the example, if (variable) and if (DEFINED variable) function the same. Therefore, a question arises: is DEFINED really necessary? Any idea will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I notice that a variable may be defined but its value can be OFF, and in this case the variable is still defined but not ON, which means if(variable) is false while if(DEFINED variable) is still true.

```
set(INITIAL_PASS OFF)

if (DEFINED INITIAL_PASS)
  message(${INITIAL_PASS})
endif()

if (INITIAL_PASS)
  MESSAGE(${INITIAL_PASS})
endif()

set(INITIAL_PASS ON)

if (DEFINED INITIAL_PASS)
  message(${INITIAL_PASS})
endif()

if (INITIAL_PASS)
  MESSAGE(${INITIAL_PASS})
endif()
```